# How to use Hibernate @Index annotation properly?

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, indices

i have a java class used as an entity that has 2 classes that inherit from it. this class has some indices but these indices didn't appear in the database. this is my java super class code

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.persistence.Version;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
@Table(name="service", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"name"})})
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = "service", 
                                 indexes = { @Index(name = "service_name", columnNames = { "name" }), 
                                 @Index(name = "service_description", columnNames = { "description" }),
                                 @Index(name = "service_accessNumber", columnNames = { "access_number" })   
                     })
public class Service implements Serializable {

@Column(name="access_number",length = 95,nullable=false)
    String accessNumber;

@Column(length=80,nullable=false)
    String name;

@Column(length=140)
    String description;

}
```

does any one know what is my problem
Note: i have this problem in my all java classes but this is one of them. the code in all class is the same of this

**Edit**: i build an xml file and put it in a grails project, and when i run this project, database created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have the same problem, but i found it's solution and it works fine with me try it, it may help you

```
in your DataSource.groovy file in your grails project make sure that under 
environment dbCreate is not equal to "update": if it is equal to "update", change 
it to "create".
```

This works fine just try it

Comment: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1012 bug fixed, now work with `update` too.

Answer (score 2):

Would a single @Table annotation work? I haven't tried it, I guess the Hibernate @Table might be overridden by JPA @Table.

You may also try @Index annotation on the column fields:

```
public class Service implements Serializable {
    @Index(name="service_accessnumber")
    @Column(name="access_number",length = 95,nullable=false)
    String accessNumber;

    @Index(name="service_name")
    @Column(length=80,nullable=false)
    String name;

    @Index(name="service_description")
    @Column(length=140)
    String description;
}
```

Comment: Did hibernate try to recreate the tables? I.e., have you set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create-drop?

Comment: i remove the database and apply create-drop, but the problem didn't solve. there is no indexes in the database appears

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL, I'm sure this work for me. As Service is a superclass in your case, what's @Inheritance strategy do you use? A mapped-superclass won't work because only one index for each index-name will be created. See also [How to auto generate names for @Index annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290495).

Comment: And, have you tried to remove all the `@Table` annotations? Maybe hibernate ignored all @Index-es when @Table exists? The unique constraint may be specified by annotate @NaturalId on the name column.

Comment: i try to remove @Table annotations but the problem didn't solve

Comment: Can you post the hibernate output logs? Or the related source code in github?

Comment: i build an xml file and put it in a grails project, and when i run this project, database created

Comment: I couldn't see what's wrong without further information. But the annotations you used should be correct.

Comment: i know that, and all references i refer to, used the same annotations, but i don't know what is the problem. i have also a spring project used this database. i think that the problem is with grails project, i try to run the spring project to create the database, do you know the method i can use it (or script) to auto create the database when running spring project

Comment: btw, regardless of the question, It still works for me to put the 2 @Table annotation (i wanted unique constraints and indices on multiple columns).